# No non-OData HTTP route registered

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, odata

I followed [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-dotnet-rest-service-aspnet-api-sql-database) tutorial to create a WebAPI REST service.

After that, I could load the list of all contacts by pointing at `http://baseaddress/api/Contacts`.

Then I added the following code in the `Register` method in WebApiConfig.cs in order to enable an OData endpoint:

```
config.Count().Filter().OrderBy().Expand().Select().MaxTop(null);

ODataModelBuilder builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
builder.EntitySet<Contact>("Contacts");
config.MapODataServiceRoute(
    routeName: "OData",
    routePrefix: "odata",
    model: builder.GetEdmModel());
```

And also added the `[EnableQuery]` parameter on the `Contact.GetContacts()` method. That way, I am able to query for particular contacts like this:

```
http://baseaddress/odata/Contacts?$filter=startswith(Name,'A')
```

and it works like charm.

Unfortunately, when I put the `[EnableQuery]`, the WebAPI endpoint stops working, showing instead the following error:

```
No non-OData HTTP route registered.

in System.Web.OData.Extensions.HttpConfigurationExtensions.GetNonODataRootContainer(HttpConfiguration configuration)
in System.Web.OData.Extensions.HttpRequestMessageExtensions.GetRootContainer(HttpRequestMessage request, String routeName)
in System.Web.OData.Extensions.HttpRequestMessageExtensions.CreateRequestScope(HttpRequestMessage request, String routeName)
in System.Web.OData.Extensions.HttpRequestMessageExtensions.CreateRequestContainer(HttpRequestMessage request, String routeName)
...
```

What should I do to fix this?

Comment: Was there any answer to this? I'm encountering the same issue.

Comment: @MichaelBowman Unfortunately no

Answer (score 29):

I encountered this problem, and since I'm working with dependency injections I  managed to solve this by adding `GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.EnableDependencyInjection()` to my `startup.cs`

ex.

```
using System.Web.OData.Extensions;
public class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.EnableDependencyInjection();
    }
}
```

Comment: If you aren't using GlobalConfiguration, modify the above like:
`var httpConfiguration = new HttpConfiguration();`
`httpConfiguration.EnableDependencyInjection();`
`var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, (Uri)Request.Url);`
`request.SetConfiguration(httpConfiguration);`
</code>

Comment: I'm **NOT** using DI, but now I have this code in my `App_Start/WebApiConfig.cs` - which *indeed makes it work..* but it makes no sense

Comment: I really didn't think this would fix my issue - but it did. I hadn't twigged this isn't just a pipeline or MVC thing it is in the odata namespace, so no danger of side effects.

Answer (score 6):

Adding `config.EnableDependencyInjection()` in `Startup.cs` worked for me.

```
var config = new HttpConfiguration();

config.EnableDependencyInjection();
```

Answer (score 5):

The key with this issue is to use `.EnableDependencyInjection()` on `Configure` method in `Startup.cs`

> If you are using ASP.net Core **endpoint routing** (recommended if you
> have at least .net core 3.0 and Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData v7.4.0)

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapControllers();

    endpoints.Select().Filter().OrderBy().Count().MaxTop(10);
    endpoints.EnableDependencyInjection();//This guy solves the problem    
    endpoints.MapODataRoute("odata", "odata", GetEdmModel());
});
```

> Otherwise if you are using **MVC routing** (only way available prior .net
> core 3.0 and Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData v7.4.0)

```
app.UseMvc(routeBuilder =>
{
    routeBuilder.Select().Filter().OrderBy().Count().MaxTop(10);
    routeBuilder.EnableDependencyInjection();//This guy solves the problem
    routeBuilder.MapODataServiceRoute("odata", "odata", GetEdmModel());
});
```

Further reading: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/odata/enabling-endpoint-routing-in-odata/

Answer (score 3):

I got this error after updating my WebApi project dependencies (NuGet) to:

- Microsoft.AspNet.OData, version="7.0.1"
- Microsoft.OData.Core, version="7.5.0"
- Microsoft.OData.Edm, version="7.5.0"
- Microsoft.Spatial, version="7.5.0"

After downgrading to the versions I used before, the error was gone again:

- Microsoft.AspNet.OData, version="5.8.0"
- Microsoft.OData.Core, version="6.19.0"
- Microsoft.OData.Edm, version="6.19.0"
- Microsoft.Spatial, version="6.19.0"

Comment: This is because with the new OData version the dependency injection model has changed. The suggested httpConfiguration.EnableDependencyInjection(); above allow the code to work with new OData version.

Answer (score 2):

I encountered this problem before and by the adding the line below it worked for me

```
protected void Application_Start()
            {  
         GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.EnableDependencyInjection();
             ....  }
```

Answer (score 1):

that problem I solved this way:

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
       .... existing code...

        //added:
        //(OData need this)
        config.EnableDependencyInjection();
        config.Expand().Select().OrderBy().Filter();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I got the above error even though I had a separate project, **which had no Odata code at all**. So this was a very strange message to get.

My solution was to *delete all the packages from the `packages` folder*. After that it worked again. Some Odata packages were still in the this folder.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had a web site with ODATA routes (and controllers), and other API routes (and controllers). What happened was my other routes were simply conflicting with ODATA ones, even with different C# namespaces and classes, etc.

Initially my controller was like this for example:

```
public class UserController : ApiController
{
    [HttpPost]
    public void Create([FromBody] string email)
    {
    }
}
```

I also had a "User" route in ODATA somewhere (different namespace, different urls, etc.). So I had to add explicitely the Route attribute, like this:

```
public class UserController : ApiController
{
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("api/user/create")]
    public void Create([FromBody] string email)
    {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I also got this error, and in my case it was an issue with case-sensitivity. I had called

`https://www.example.com/odata/MyEntities` instead of

`https://www.example.com/odata/myentities`, as it was registered.

Be sure to check your route configuration and calling url.

Answer (score 0):

the controller name has to match the name you put in `builder.EntitySet<SomeType>()`

```
public class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder appBuilder)
    {
        var config = new HttpConfiguration();

        config.Count().Filter().OrderBy().Expand().Select();

        var builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
        builder.EntitySet<Order>("Order");// now the controller must be named OrderController
        
        config.MapODataServiceRoute(routeName: "odata", routePrefix: null, model: builder.GetEdmModel());
        
        appBuilder.UseWebApi(config);
    }
}

public class OrderController : ODataController
{
    // test data source
    public List<Order> OrdersList { get; set; } = new List<Order>()
    {
        // put some test data
    };

    [HttpGet]
    [EnableQuery]
    public IQueryable<Order> Get() //Get: http://localhost:port/Order
    { 
        return Orders.AsQueryable();
    }

    [HttpGet]
    [EnableQuery]
    public Order Get(int key) //Get: http://localhost:port/Order(key)
    {
        return Orders.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ID == key); 
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public bool Post(Order entity) //Post: http://localhost:port/Order
    {
        Orders.Add(entity);
        return true;
    }

    [HttpPut]
    public bool Put(int key, Order entity) //Put: http://localhost:port/Order(key)
    {
        var idx = Orders.FindIndex(x => x.ID == key);
        Orders[idx] = entity;
        return true;
    }

    [HttpPatch]
    public bool Patch(int key, Order entity) //Patch: http://localhost:port/Order(key)
    {
        var idx = Orders.FindIndex(x => x.ID == key);
        Orders[idx] = entity;
        return true;
    }

    [HttpDelete]
    public bool Delete(int key) //Delete: http://localhost:port/Order(key)
    {
        var idx = Orders.FindIndex(x => x.ID == key);
        Orders.RemoveAt(idx);
        return true;
    }
}
```

PS: am using Microsoft.AspNet.OData 7.5.5

Answer (score 0):

I just migrate from core 2.1 to .net core 3.1, and have the same issue. Here is how I fix:

```
 app.UseMvc(routeBuilder =>
        {
            routeBuilder.EnableDependencyInjection(); //..another config
        });
```